# How do I open a word document via VBA macro in read write more and write Text into the Document?

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am getting the  Message

1. Open Read only
2. Local Copy
3. Recieve Notification when available
   I need to open the doc in the read write mode, and the document is closed before the macro is executed

Also I ahve doubts on the way I am writing the Text

```
Sub Read_Write_Document()

  Dim p As Long, r As Long
  Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

  wrdApp.Visible = True

  Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Word_File_read_write_1.docx")

  Dim i As Integer
  i = 1
  With wrdDoc_Read
      For p = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
          Set tRange = .Range(Start:=.Paragraphs(p).Range.Start, End:=.Paragraphs(p).Range.End)
           tString = tRange.Text
           tString = Left(tString, Len(tString) - 1)

           If InStr(1, tString, "1") > 0 Then
              If Mid(tString, 1, 4) = "date" Then 
                  tRange.Text = "DATE" ' Write Text
              End If
          End If
      Next p
  End With
  .SaveAs ("C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\Word_File_read_write_2.docx") 
  wrdApp.Quit ' close the Word application
  Set wrdDoc = Nothing
  Set wrdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things

**A**

It's always advisable to use `Option Explicit`

You have declared the word document as `wrdDoc` but are using `wrdDoc_Read`

Change the line

```
With wrdDoc_Read
```

to

```
With wrdDoc
```

**B**

Next your `.SaveAs` routine is outside the `With - End With` and hence will give you error

**C**

You are directly quitting the word application without closing the word document. It's always good to issue a `wrdDoc.Close (False)` after a `.SaveAs` because there are instances where an installed add-in can make changes to your document and quitting the word application will prompt the `.SaveAs` again.

**D**

Instead of looping through the cells and replacing the text, you can use `.Find` and `Replace`